# How can I fix this error - opening py2app?

Tags: python, py2app

I want to build my app with py2app to have the actuall .app file to run on other macs.

here's my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

I can't get it to open after it's been successfully built.
I get Open console / terminate
and in the console there's nothing useful

If I open the package contents and run the main file this shows up:

```
    from interface.root_component import Root
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "interface/root_component.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "interface/credentials_component.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/fernet.pyc", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
2021-08-04 16:04:21.627 main[39129:34503064] main Error
```

I tried reinstalling CFFI, I can see it's related to the cryptography module but I'm not sure how else I can include it.
Thank you!

Comment: You may need to use [`-i` or `-p`](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#option-reference) to explicitly include `cffi` or `_cffi_backend`...

Comment: @AKX What do they do and where do I pass them? How?

Comment: I used 
```python3 setup.py py2app -i cryptography,cffi
``` and it worked,
thank you!